# single vs multi application on one apache server

Tags: php, performance, apache

I want to run a SaaS service and I'm going to deploy a new instance of my PHP application for every new user on my Apache server.

I want to know if this going to affect the performance of my server or it only depends on the number of requests for these services.

Comment: Should only be affected by requests. not by files.

Comment: Request made on your and amount of data served by those requests will affect it

Comment: Can any one give me some reference to read more about this subject.